# Object in Angular Constant changing attributes values

Tags: angularjs, constants

I have this constant:

```
(function(angular) {
    app.constant('Session', {
        user : null,
    });
})(window.angular);
```

And i can do something like this (it's working fine):

```
(function(angular) {
    app.service('LoginService', [
        'Session',
        function(Session) {
            var doLogin =function(loginCredentials) {
                console.log('do login');

                var userData = {
                    avatar: 'img/logo.png',
                    nome: 'John Smith',
                    email: 'jsmail@gmail.com',
                    telefone: '1223334',
                    senha: 'abc123',
                    moradias : [
                        {
                            torre: 'Le Parc II',
                            numero: 'Apto. 2002'
                        },
                        {
                            torre: 'Le Parc XVI',
                            numero: 'Apto. 122'
                        },                  
                        {
                            torre: 'Le Parc Residences',
                            numero: 'Nº 122'
                        }
                    ]
                }

                Session.user = userData;
                return true;
            }...
```

It should work? Or it's an issue?

I'm thinking it maybe should happen because i'm nothing changing the constant structure, but the value of one attribute of it.

Comment: Your constant is an object, which has a property. And you can mutate the properties of objects in JavaScript. You could use a getter, and no setter, if you wanted the property to be immutable.

Comment: Yeah. Me and the other developers here had discussed this, I acctually post this to get other opinions.

Comment: _" I acctually post this to get other opinions"_  I'd rather want facts. FWIW: You can freeze an object if it should be "really" constant.